# jQuery .on() combined with Modernizr.prefixed()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just try to understand a jQuery-Script which I must use.
Now I found the following snip:

```
$currPage.addClass( outClass ).on( animEndEventName, function() {
    $currPage.off( animEndEventName );
    endCurrPage = true;
    if( endNextPage ) {
        onEndAnimation( $currPage, $nextPage );
    }
});
```

Explenation what I already know:
`$currPage`: This is the current page. It's a `<div class="page">`
`endCurrPage`: This is a boolean which is in standard false
`endNextPage`: Is similar to the `endCurrPage`

My question is the `.on( animEndEventName,` part. The `animEndEventName` variable looks like that:

```
var animEndEventNames = {
    'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
    'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
    'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
    'animation' : 'animationend'
},
animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
```

This code is by Modernizr.prefixed(): http://modernizr.com/docs/#prefixed

jQuery's `.on()` wait for an event, here `animEndEventName`. So how this actually works? I don't understand exactly this part...

I hope You can help me. If you need more code, just say it. But I think this is the relevant part.

Comment: are you asking for a code review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation')
```

This will return the appropriate "prefixed" event name for your current browser.  For instance, in IE it will return "msAnimation".

```
animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ];
```

This will then take that value and look it up in `animEndEventNames` to get the matching end event name.  For IE, "MSAnimationEnd".

```
$currPage.on( animEndEventName,
```

This will bind a handler that will fire when the browser-appropriate animation end event is fired.

[This site](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/) has a decent explanation of why this is needed.